# How do I go about integrating a regular javascript file into my vue.js page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a js script written in pretty much the same syntax as one would write one without vue.js, although I haven't included semicolons (not sure how this might help but throwing it in there anyway).

I'm curious as to whether I should put this script into the format of one object with multiple methods and data/variables as properties of that object, similar to how it is written at the bottom of a vue.js page.

I'm entirely new to vue, but not to JavaScript.

If I have some script called `myscript.js`, and I want to include this file, its functions and variables, in a `.vue` file (not in the main.js file, because I don't want it to be loaded on every page, just the one I'm working with), how exactly should I go about including it in the file?

I am extremely aware as to how vague this is, and I'm absolutely happy to elaborate, but at the moment my mind is unable to intuitively explain exactly what I mean (mostly out of exhaustion unrelated to programming).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you are using Vue, how you are building it. Basically this is a general toolchain question. If you are using a module loader or bundler, you can just `import './myscript.js';`. Also, use semicolons and strict mode.

Comment: I'm trying to access the functions, after importing, but the console returns an error of `(the name of my function) is not a function`. I'm using Vue with Node.js, if this is any help

Comment: I see but I can't help without understanding your build process. You need to understand the process to explain it however, and Vue primarily runs in a browser so, while your build tools run under NodeJS, it's incorrect to say you are using Vue with NodeJS which implies Vue is running on top of NodeJS. So, are you using Vue CLI, Webpack, SystemJS, [Insert your toolchain(s) here]?

Answer (score 0):

JS code can be imported in the JS part of `.vue` files exactly as you'd import regular JS files. You don't need to import Vue components, it can be anything you can import normally - data, functions, objects, etc. Minimal example:

```js
// name.js
export default 'John Doe';

// Hello.vue
<template>
  <p>Hello, my name is {{fullName}}!</p>
</template>
<script>
import name from './name';
export default {
  data() { return {
    fullName: name,
  }}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use in .vue file`require('./myscript.js')` and  use strict directive by adding `use strict;` to the beginning the script

EDIT : you have to export your functions in myscript.js file

```
// myscript.js
export function fn1() {...} 
export function fn2() {...}
```

and then import them in your vue file

```
import * as MyFn from './myscript.js'

MyFn.fn1();
MyFn.fn2();
```

Comment: @rwn did you export your functions ?